# Webkit Storage pulled out from under me

Tags: google-chrome, jquery-mobile, webkit, cordova, persistence

Uncaught reference error: window.webkitStorageInfo is deprecated

I am using jQuery mobile and persistance.js (still learning it). I have been using chrome to debug and have been making progress on my projects over the past month, but now chrome is telling me that persistance is not loading anymore. I have to assume that this is because persistance uses webkitStorage, but I cannot seem to find that line anywhere in the code.

Is there anyone out there who has dealt with this already, or who can walk me through a fix, or suggest an alternative storage system that is compliant to current standards?

(I am planning on porting to phoneGap eventually FYI)

my git repo: https://github.com/WilliamSS/ToDo-Base-jqm-pjs.git

Answer (score 0):

as it turns out, I missed the NotScripts app running on Chrome that was auto denying all scripts until I set a password.